# WebDriverBackedSelenium with IE Error "Could not start a new session"

Tags: internet-explorer-9, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run a test script using the **WebDriverBackedSelenium** in IE. I have tested the same script on **firefox** and **chrome** and it works fine.

Here is what I do in my **setup method**

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    selenium1 = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "http://www.example.com");
```

When I run this script the IE browser window opens up and after few time I get the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d', time: '2013-02-27 20:53:56'

System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_25'
```

Also in the browser

```
http://--port=24284/
```

is shown.

I am using **IE version 9**.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see at least one mistake what you are doing:

The Internet Explorer driver has to be downloaded from [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list)

and then you have to point out to the exe you unzipped and **not** to the Internet Explorer itself

Comment: Yes, This was the problem and I had fixed it.
Still thanks for the reply.